# SQLite EF6 error

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

Im using win10, vs2017.
I created a new project, then added nuget "System.Data.SQLite".
Next, I installed "sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.105.2.exe" from system.data.sqlite.org with fullInstall options and checkboxes.
I rebooted the PC.
Then in the Visual Studio Server Explorer, I connected a new SQLite Database.
Further added "ADO .Net Entity Date Model", added Entity and used "Generate DB from model"
Im getting this error:
[image: DB Generator Wizzard]
App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\DeleteThis\Test.db&quot;;version=3'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

SSDLToSQL10.tt:

```
<# 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This T4 template generates T-SQL from an instance of 
// System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection, an object representation
// of the SSDL. This T-SQL is compatible with SQL 2012, 2008, 2005, CE, and Azure databases.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Note: We will resolve all paths in assembly directives at runtime, taking 
// macros and environment variables into account (e.g. $(ProjectDir), $(DevEnvDir) etc.)
#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(DevEnvDir)..\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration.dll"#>
<#@ assembly name="$(DevEnvDir)..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll"#>
<#@ assembly name="$(DevEnvDir)..\IDE\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(DevEnvDir)..\IDE\EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ include file="GenerateTSQL.Utility.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension = ".sql" #>
<#

// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Setup for the template (initializing variables, etc.)
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    string databaseName = this.GetInput<string>(EdmParameterBag.ParameterName.DatabaseName.ToString());
    string edmxPath = this.GetInput<string>(EdmParameterBag.ParameterName.EdmxPath.ToString());
    Version targetVersion = this.GetInput<Version>(EdmParameterBag.ParameterName.TargetVersion.ToString());

    DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new TemplateDbConfiguration());

    if (false == InitializeAndValidateExistingStore()) 
    {
#>
-- Warning: There were errors validating the existing SSDL. Drop statements
-- will not be generated.
<#
    }
#>
-- --------------------------------------------------
<#
    if (this.IsSQLCE) {
#>
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server Compact Edition
<#
    } else {
#>
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and Azure
<#
    }
#>
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: <#=DateTime.Now#>
<#
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(edmxPath))
    {
#>
-- Generated from EDMX file: <#=Id(edmxPath)#>
<#
    }
#>
-- --------------------------------------------------

<#  if (!this.IsSQLCE) 
    { 
#>
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
<#  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
    {
#>
USE [<#=Id(databaseName)#>];
GO
<#
    }
    foreach (string unescapedSchemaName in (from es in Store.GetAllEntitySets() select es.GetSchemaName()).Distinct())
    {
#>
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'<#=Lit(unescapedSchemaName)#>') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [<#=Id(unescapedSchemaName)#>]');
<#
    }
#>
GO
<#  } #>

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
<#  if (this.IsSQLCE)
    {
#>
-- NOTE: if the constraint does not exist, an ignorable error will be reported.
<#  } #>
-- --------------------------------------------------

<#
    foreach (AssociationSet associationSet in ExistingStore.GetAllAssociationSets())
    {
        ReferentialConstraint constraint = associationSet.ElementType.ReferentialConstraints.Single();
        string constraintName = Id(WriteFKConstraintName(constraint));
        AssociationSetEnd dependentSetEnd = associationSet.AssociationSetEnds.Where(ase => ase.CorrespondingAssociationEndMember == constraint.ToRole).Single();
        string schemaName = Id(dependentSetEnd.EntitySet.GetSchemaName());
        string dependentTableName = Id(dependentSetEnd.EntitySet.GetTableName());

        if (!this.IsSQLCE)
        {
#>
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[<#=Lit(schemaName)#>].[<#=Lit(constraintName)#>]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
<#      } #>
    ALTER TABLE <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=dependentTableName#>] DROP CONSTRAINT [<#=constraintName#>];
GO
<#
    }
#>

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing tables
<#  if (this.IsSQLCE)
    {
#>
-- NOTE: if the table does not exist, an ignorable error will be reported.
<#  } #>
-- --------------------------------------------------

<#
    foreach (EntitySet entitySet in ExistingStore.GetAllEntitySets())
    { 
        string schemaName = Id(entitySet.GetSchemaName());
        string tableName = Id(entitySet.GetTableName());

        if (!this.IsSQLCE)
        {
#>
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[<#=Lit(schemaName)#>].[<#=Lit(tableName)#>]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
<#      } #>
    DROP TABLE <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=tableName#>];
GO
<#
    }
#>

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

<#
    foreach (EntitySet entitySet in Store.GetAllEntitySets())
    {
        string schemaName = Id(entitySet.GetSchemaName());
        string tableName = Id(entitySet.GetTableName());
#>
-- Creating table '<#=tableName#>'
CREATE TABLE <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=tableName#>] (
<#
        for (int p = 0; p < entitySet.ElementType.Properties.Count; p++)
        {
            EdmProperty prop = entitySet.ElementType.Properties[p];
#>
    [<#=Id(prop.Name)#>] <#=prop.ToStoreType()#> <#=WriteIdentity(prop, targetVersion)#> <#=WriteNullable(prop.Nullable)#><#=(p < entitySet.ElementType.Properties.Count - 1) ? "," : ""#>
<#
        }
#>
);
GO

<# 
    } 
#>
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

<#
    foreach (EntitySet entitySet in Store.GetAllEntitySets())
    {
        string schemaName = Id(entitySet.GetSchemaName());
        string tableName = Id(entitySet.GetTableName());
#>
-- Creating primary key on <#=WriteColumns(entitySet.ElementType.GetKeyProperties(), ',')#> in table '<#=tableName#>'
ALTER TABLE <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=tableName#>]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_<#=tableName#>]
    PRIMARY KEY <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>CLUSTERED <#}#>(<#=WriteColumns(entitySet.ElementType.GetKeyProperties(), ',')#> <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>ASC<#}#>);
GO

<#
    }
#>
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

<#
    foreach (AssociationSet associationSet in Store.GetAllAssociationSets())
    {
        ReferentialConstraint constraint = associationSet.ElementType.ReferentialConstraints.Single();
        AssociationSetEnd dependentSetEnd = associationSet.AssociationSetEnds.Where(ase => ase.CorrespondingAssociationEndMember == constraint.ToRole).Single();
        AssociationSetEnd principalSetEnd = associationSet.AssociationSetEnds.Where(ase => ase.CorrespondingAssociationEndMember == constraint.FromRole).Single();
        string schemaName = Id(dependentSetEnd.EntitySet.GetSchemaName());
        string dependentTableName = Id(dependentSetEnd.EntitySet.GetTableName());
        string principalTableName = Id(principalSetEnd.EntitySet.GetTableName());
#>
-- Creating foreign key on <#=WriteColumns(constraint.ToProperties, ',')#> in table '<#=dependentTableName#>'
ALTER TABLE <#if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=dependentTableName#>]
ADD CONSTRAINT [<#=WriteFKConstraintName(constraint)#>]
    FOREIGN KEY (<#=WriteColumns(constraint.ToProperties, ',')#>)
    REFERENCES <# if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=principalTableName#>]
        (<#=WriteColumns(constraint.FromProperties, ',')#>)
    ON DELETE <#=GetDeleteAction(constraint)#> ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

<#      
        // if the foreign keys are part of the primary key on the dependent end, then we should not add a constraint.
        if (!dependentSetEnd.EntitySet.ElementType.GetKeyProperties().Take(constraint.ToProperties.Count()).OrderBy(r => r.Name).SequenceEqual(constraint.ToProperties.OrderBy(r => r.Name)))
        {
#>
-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY '<#=WriteFKConstraintName(constraint)#>'
CREATE INDEX [IX_<#=WriteFKConstraintName(constraint)#>]
ON <#if (!IsSQLCE) {#>[<#=schemaName#>].<#}#>[<#=dependentTableName#>]
    (<#=WriteColumns(constraint.ToProperties, ',')#>);
GO

<#      
        }
    }
#>
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Script has ended
-- --------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature does not work for SQLite, as hinted at in the tt file:

```
<#
    if (this.IsSQLCE) {
#>
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server Compact Edition
<#
    } else {
#>
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and Azure
<#
    }
#>
```

Comment: This is auto default generated code. I deleted this part, but the error remained the same

Comment: The feature you use does not work with SQLite (as I said)

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks